# How can I make the button on my headphones control something other than the stock music player?

Tags: music-player, hardware, buttons, headphones

When I press this button, it plays/pauses the stock music player. I don't use the stock music player--I use a comination of [Last.fm](https://market.android.com/details?id=fm.last.android), [Grooveshark](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.grooveshark.android.v1), and [Winamp](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nullsoft.winamp). I would like to make the button play/pause whichever player I am currently using. If this isn't possible, I would like it to simply control Winamp, instead of the default player.

I am using Android 2.1 (unrooted) on a Samsung Fascinate.

Answer (score 2):

*To get the headset to control only one application:*

The application has to support receiving headset control events.

In the case of Winamp, press menu --> Settings --> Enable "Control headset"

If there are multiple apps that accept headset controls, you may have to disable the feature on the other apps (I'm not certain which app gets priority over another).

Comment: I can't seem to figure out how to disable it in the stock music player. Does anyone know how to disable it (fyi, I believe the stock player in Galaxy S phones is different from stock Android).

Comment: I've found that I don't have to disable it on other apps, it seems to work with whichever I've activated most recently.  I generally toggle between Meridian and BeyondPod.

If I toggle Meridian in as accepting headphone button commands (without disabling BeyondPod first), it works for Meridian.  to get BeyondPod Back, I have to disable and re-enable it.

More notes here: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7190/change-default-application-for-handling-headset-controls