# Change default application for handling headset controls

Tags: headphones, buttons

I have a HTC Desire HD running stock 2.2

When using the HTC supplied headphones, the play/pause/nav controls only work with Meridian. I don't remember explicitly setting it up as such, although I may have missed it. I'd like to be able to use them with BeyondPod instead, as I'm about 10x more likely to be listening to a podcast than music.

Is there a way to change the default app for these buttons?

Comment: Similar problem but with different music apps http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5994/how-can-i-make-the-button-on-my-headphones-control-something-other-than-the-stock are there any similar options in Meridian?

Comment: So I had this page open on another tab for ages before I saw I hadn't saved the comment. Probably would've been more helpful before you found the answer yourself!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit more playing around led me to a (if not THE) solution.  I found an "enable headset buttons" check box in Meridian, which prompted me to dig further into BeyondPod, where a found a similar setting.

Everything works as I'd like now.

I've since gone back and checked a couple of things though, which are not quite as I expected.  I thought if you re-enabled the controls within one app, it might disable the other.  This isn't quite what happened. When I re-enabled Meridian, it responded to the controls, although BeyondPod still showed it as supposedly responding, which it didn't.  Once I'd disabled Meridian again, I had to go back into BeyondPod, disable and re-enable it's control in order to have it respond again.

My main gripe was that if I were listening a podcast, and bumped the headphone controls, the music would start playing over the top of my podcast audio.  While it may be a cute multi-tasking demo, it's not a particularly practical use of this feature, IMH(BC)O.

Comment: To clarify: You disabled Meridian from receiving headset actions, and enabled BeyondPod. And you're now using your headset to only control BeyondPod, not *both* Meridian and BeyondPod?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.